# Far anchor calling in html5 browsers

Tags: html

Anchor in html5 - all current Windows-browsers

hello -

ok, I DID know how anhcors work(ed).

While IE6 on my XP-working computer can do things like call for an ancor over 5 or more levels, type :

```
<a href "../../../a-directory/b-directory/c-directory/myfile.htm#someanchor>Jump to someancor </a>
```

all latest browsers - firefox, opera, chrome, IE9 on Win 7 refuse to do these jumps. The only execute the program myfile.htm, but do not continue to go to #someanchor; locally on that program `#someanchor` works ok. It is the ouside reach to `#someanchor` that does not work. Maybe my string is too long - anybody any idea how long that whole call is allowed to be??

My doctype line still refers to HTML4.01 though.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, are you trying to use named anchors to navigate within the same page?

Answer (score 0):

I did some meddling in the meantime and it seems to work:

This ancor-calling with all modern browsers worked the very moment when I replaced the HTML 4.01 doctype statement by  HTML5-doctype, meaning: "doctype html" (replaceing the brackets here for a moment  with " ..."). And some of my ancors looked like 1025a23 so I additionally inserted a letter up front like M1025a23 - maybe that was an unnecessary step, though.

ok - live and learn. There will be more browser surprises yet ahead, I figure. That much for proper downgrading in browsers  ????

UZinsm.